# How do I run test-path on all paths in the system variable PATH using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I would like to run the Test-Path, or something similar the completes my purpose to find the invalid paths in my path variable.

The main thing I have done is search for

```
test path system variable for invalid entries
```

This did not find anything.

This example is just to show I have tried something, but I don't really know what the best command it.

```
Test-Path -Path %Path% -PathType Any
```

### Update

These scripts enabled my to find a couple bad paths and fix them

Comment: `$env:Path -split ';'|?{-not($_|Test-Path)}`

Comment: the path is a string with semi-colon delimiters. so load `$env:path`, split it on the `;`, and send the resulting directory items to `Test-Path`.

Comment: `$env:Path -split ';'|?{$_ -and -not($_|Test-Path)}` then :)

Comment: @HarlanNelson, please don't edit (unsuccessful) solution attempts into your question; it's better to provide feedback via comments. Mathias has already addressed your problem re empty entries, and Panomosh's solution is easy to adapt analogously (`if ($path -and (Test-Path $path))`). As an aside: In PowerShell (Core) 7+, `Test-Path` now reports `$false` if `''` (empty string) is passed as the path rather than an error (`$null` still causes an error).

Comment: @mklement0  I just cut and pasted, no editing.  If the codes are different, I can't explain that, maybe I didn't capture the entire code when a copied.  I can re-cut and paste if needed.  I will take that part out.  looks my powershell is on an old version.

Comment: Thanks for updating, @HarlanNelson. The error messages you've been getting imply that you're using _Windows PowerShell_, the legacy, ships-with-Windows, no longer actively developed edition of PowerShell, as opposed to the cross-platform, install-on-demand, actively developed [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition. Yes, Mathias' _original_ comment didn't take empty entries into account, which cause errors in Windows PowerShell, but his second comment provided a fix.

Comment: @mklement0 ,My apologies if posting the running of the suggestions violated etiquette. I noticed those solutions have been removed.  I just had the two versions of powershell explained to me.  But I was not sure what post to mark as the answer, now that there is only one possibility, that decision was make easy.

Comment: @HarlanNelson, thank you for your thoughtful feedback, and thanks for acting on the advice. If a given answer doesn't work for you, it's best to seek resolution together with the answerer via comments (which should be removed if and when resolution has been achieved; you can delete your own comments and flag others' as "no longer needed") - if the problem can't be resolved, posting a _new_ question may be called for.
If multiple answers solve your problem, but you can't decide which one should be accepted, it's fine not to
accept any - a comment to that effect helps.

Comment: P.S.: Just to clarify: I'm just a regular user too (but I've been around a long time), so this my personal advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on [Mathias R. Jessen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) great solution in a comment:

```sh
# Output those PATH entries that refer to nonexistent dirs.
# Works on both Windows and Unix-like platforms.
$env:PATH -split [IO.Path]::PathSeparator -ne '' |
  Where-Object { -not (Test-Path $_) }
```

- Using the all uppercase form `PATH` of the variable name and [`[IO.Path]::PathSeparator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.PathSeparator) as the separator to [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) by makes the command cross-platform:

  - On Unix-like platforms environment variable names are case-sensitive, so using `$env:PATH` (all-upercase) is required; by contrast, Windows is not case-sensitive, so `$env:PATH` works there too, even though the actual case of the name is `Path`.
  - On Unix-like platforms, `:` separates the entries in `$env:PATH`, whereas it is `;` on Windows - `[IO.Path]::PathSeparator` returns the platform-appropriate character.
- `-ne ''` filters out any empty tokens resulting from the `-split` operation, which could result from directly adjacent separators in the variable value (e.g., `;;`) - such empty entries have no effect and can be ignored.

  - Note: With a an *array* as the LHS, such as returned by `-split`, PowerShell comparison operators such as `-eq` and `-ne` act as *filters* and return an *array of matching items* rather than a Boolean - see [about_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#common-features).
- The [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) call filters the input directory paths down to those that do *not* exist, and outputs them (which prints to the display by default).

  - Note that, strictly speaking, [`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path)'s first positional parameter is `-Path`, which interprets its argument as a [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards).
  - For full robustness, `Test-Path -LiteralPath $_` is needed, to rule out inadvertent interpretation of literal paths that happen to contain `[` as wildcards - though with entries in `$env:PATH` that seems unlikely.